# Numpy array with different standard deviation per row

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, gaussian, normal-distribution

I'd like to get an `NxM` matrix where numbers in each row are random samples generated from different normal distributions(same `mean` but different standard deviations). The following code works:

```
import numpy as np

mean = 0.0 # same mean
stds = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0] # different stds
matrix = np.random.random((3,10))

for i,std in enumerate(stds):
     matrix[i] = np.random.normal(mean, std, matrix.shape[1])
```

However, this code is not quite efficient as there is a `for` loop involved. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`np.random.normal()` is vectorized](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html); you can switch axes and transpose the result:

```
np.random.seed(444)
arr = np.random.normal(loc=0., scale=[1., 2., 3.], size=(1000, 3)).T

print(arr.mean(axis=1))
# [-0.06678394 -0.12606733 -0.04992722]
print(arr.std(axis=1))
# [0.99080274 2.03563299 3.01426507]
```

That is, the `scale` parameter is the *column-wise* standard deviation, hence the need to transpose via `.T` since you want row-wise inputs.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
rows = 10000
stds = [1, 5, 10]

data = np.random.normal(size=(rows, len(stds)))
scaled = data * stds

print(np.std(scaled, axis=0))
```

Output:

```
[ 0.99417905  5.00908719 10.02930637]
```

This exploits the fact that a two normal distributions can be interconverted by linear scaling (in this case, multiplying by standard deviation). In the output, each column (second axis) will contain a normally distributed variable corresponding to a value in `stds`.